# RSpec, Capybara and Stripe failing on required product field

Tags: rspec, stripe-payments, rspec-rails

I am attempting to mock an API process that is being used with Stripe. In the app, a button is being used to call to the Charge API. I haven't seen this in any online resources, which all point to use the Plan API. The following runs alright except that it's looking for a required **product** field. Other tutorials such as [Mocking Stripe with Rspec](https://www.monkeyvault.net/mocking-stripe-with-rspec/) don't include the product parameter at all. I've also attempted to mock it using the value in Stripe's [API Reference](https://stripe.com/docs/api/plans/create) and other hardcoded values but it says *product does not exist*. I have tried working with this in either or both `plan =` statements

```
context "stripe processor" do
        let(:stripe_helper) { StripeMock.create_test_helper }

        it "creates a stripe plan" do
          plan = stripe_helper.create_plan(:id => 'my_plan', :amount => 1500)

          # The above line replaces the following:
          plan = Stripe::Plan.create(
            :id => 'my_plan',
            :name => 'StripeMock Default Plan ID',
            :amount => 1500,
            :currency => 'usd',
            :interval => 'month'
          )
          expect(plan.id).to eq('my_plan')
          expect(plan.amount).to eq(1500)
        end
    end
```

Note that I am using the [stripe-ruby-mock](https://stripe.com/docs/api/plans/create) gem. Thank you to anyone who may have ideas. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In more recent API versions the `product` parameter refers to a Product ID, that product must exist before creating a Plan. See [this api revision](https://stripe.com/docs/upgrades#2018-02-05). For testing, you need to ensure that a given Product ID exists before creating the Plan or you'll get the error message that you see.

It's possible that you could mock out both the Product and Plan with `stripe-ruby-mock` but it looks like the gem was built before those API changes and it may need modifications to work correctly here.